# How to open apple Addressbook link in cordova

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I'm making an `app` in `Apache Cordova` and I was wondering how to open a specific contact in `Apple Contacts` with a url. As defined [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AddressBook/Tasks/URLScheme.html)

I know you can do things like tel:`+1xxxxxxxxxx`

What is the correct format for this case? Do I need to use a `plugin` similar to `Cordova contacts`?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this plugin: [cordova-plugin-contacts](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-contacts), 
it allow you to access contacts from device database.

Samlple of using are reported in link above.

Comment: I looked at that one, and it won't let me open the contacts app to a specific  contact.